# how to get JSessionID in PhantomJS

Tags: java, javascript, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I am not sure if this question is related to PhantomJS or simple Javascript.

I am using Ghostdriver to open a webpage and trying to capture the response headers. GhostDriver executes the javascript and adds the [onResourceReceived](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-received.html) event.

Like this:

```
String responsescript = 
                "var page = this,"+
                "jsonResponse = \"\";"+
                "page.onResourceReceived = function (res) {"+
                "console.log(JSON.stringify(res));" /* This line works fine but i want to pass this data somehow to java program. To do that, i came up with the below alternative but it is failing*/
                "jsonResponse = jsonResponse + JSON.stringify(res, undefined, 4);"+
                "};"+
                "function getJsonResponse(){"+
                "return jsonResponse;"+
                "}";
ghostDriver.executePhantomJS(responsescript);
ghostDriver.get("cnn.com");
ghostDriver.executePhantomJS("getJsonResponse();");
```

It always fails with the below message:

`{message=Can't find variable: getJsonResponse, line=1, stack=ReferenceError: Can't find variable: getJsonResponse`

I just want to get the response headers in some String variable in Java so that i can look for JSESSIONID in it..

Because of my poor javascript skills i am not able to solve this simple problem..

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why i took long route but after going through the examples on the ghostdriver([link](https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver/tree/master/test/java/src/test/java/ghostdriver)) ..its just 2 lines of code

So happy..now i can sleep peacefully :)

```
    String responsescript = 
                    "return JSON.stringify(this.cookies);";
    Object object = phantom.executePhantomJS(responsescript);

    System.out.println(((String)object));
```